# Send a JSON object through ShouldInterceptRequest

Tags: javascript, android, webview, httprequest

I'm using the android function ShouldInterceptRequest to intercept get requests of my webview. But I need to send some datas (a JSON object) when intercepting the request. I know that the android function has to return a WebResourceResponse object containing the mimetype, encoding and a stream containing the data I want to send. I've tried many solutions but each time I'm looking for the type of my data received in Javascript, it's always a STRING, and I absolutely need directly a JSON object (don't want to do a JSON parse).

The java code of my InputStream in my ShouldInterceptRequest :

```
stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
return new WebResourceResponse("application/json; charset=UTF-8", null, stream);
```

So, is there a way to convert a JSON object to a stream (InputStream or something else) in order to receive directly a JSON object and not a string ?

Thx for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I've found is to alter my JavaScript. Mime type has no effect.

I was using JQuery.ajax() method (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), setting dataType to JSON in the config for this method worked from me. I realise this is doing a JSON.parse indirectly but it seems to still work in the browser where it was previously detecting the type automatically, so no need to catch a parse fail because its already an object.